# Jetty BadMessage Embedded WebSocket Servlet

Tags: servlets, ssl, websocket, jetty

I have created a simple embedded WebSocket server using jetty 9.2.5.  The server works flawlessly when using an unsecured connection.  When I add an SSL connector, the client cannot connect using the https scheme, "wss" vs "ws", and I see a badMessage warning:

```
31710 [qtp6566818-16] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser  - badMessage: 400 Illegal character 0x16 in state=START in '\x16<<<\x03\x01\x00\xAb\x01\x00\x00\xA7\x03\x037%\x03d\xFf\xBd\xE8...\x01\x05\x01\x02\x01\x04\x03\x05\x03\x02\x03\x04\x02\x02\x02>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' for HttpChannelOverHttp@f59306{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-}
```

There is no problem in the client when I revert the URI to an unsecured WebSocket scheme:

```
40559 [qtp6566818-17] INFO  com.datafascia.emerge.websocketEchoService.EchoService  - Connected ... 
40562 [qtp6566818-17] INFO  com.datafascia.emerge.websocketEchoService.EchoService  - Session: WebSocketSession[websocket=JettyAnnotatedEventDriver[com.datafascia.emerge.websocketEchoService.EchoService@18c45017],behavior=SERVER,connection=WebSocketServerConnection@77882dcc{IDLE}{f=Flusher[queueSize=0,aggregateSize=0,failure=null],g=Generator[SERVER,validating],p=Parser@61ed4bc3[ExtensionStack,s=START,c=0,len=0,f=null,p=WebSocketPolicy@379e5d9e[behavior=SERVER,maxTextMessageSize=65536,maxTextMessageBufferSize=32768,maxBinaryMessageSize=65536,maxBinaryMessageBufferSize=32768,asyncWriteTimeout=60000,idleTimeout=300000,inputBufferSize=4096]]},remote=WebSocketRemoteEndpoint@2e93a9a8[batching=true],incoming=JettyAnnotatedEventDriver[com.datafascia.emerge.websocketEchoService.EchoService@18c45017],outgoing=ExtensionStack[queueSize=0,extensions=[],incoming=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession,outgoing=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerConnection]]
40571 [qtp6566818-16] INFO  com.datafascia.emerge.websocketEchoService.EchoService  - incomingMessage= 05501140317063844             123CYC     EMERGE-123C015083
40578 [qtp6566818-17] INFO  com.datafascia.emerge.websocketEchoService.EchoService  - Connection closed with statusCode: 1005, reason: null
```

The code for the server was taken pretty much from the examples I've encountered both on the jetty site and on the Internet.  Here is the code that sets up the WebSocket servlet:

```
// Setup the websocket server
Server server = new Server(websocketPort);

if (wssEnabled) {
  // Add http/s connectors
  //connector = new ServerConnector(server);
  //connector.setPort(websocketPort);

  // HTTP Configuration
  HttpConfiguration http_config = new HttpConfiguration();
  http_config.setSecureScheme("https");
  http_config.setSecurePort(8443);
  http_config.setOutputBufferSize(32768);
  http_config.setRequestHeaderSize(8192);
  http_config.setResponseHeaderSize(8192);
  http_config.setSendServerVersion(true);
  http_config.setSendDateHeader(false);

  SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
  sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath("/home/jedwards/keystore");
  logger.info("keystore path: {}", sslContextFactory.getKeyStorePath());
  sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("1deadparrot");
  sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("1deadparrot");
  sslContextFactory.setExcludeCipherSuites(
      "SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA","SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA","SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
      "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5","SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA","SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA",
      "SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA");

  // SSL HTTP Configuration
  HttpConfiguration https_config = new HttpConfiguration(http_config);
  https_config.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

  // SSL Connector
  connector = new ServerConnector(server,
      new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory,HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()),
      new HttpConnectionFactory(https_config));
  connector.setPort(8443);
  connector.setIdleTimeout(500000);
} else {
  // Basic HTTP connector
  connector = new ServerConnector(server);
  connector.setPort(websocketPort);
}
ServletContextHandler ctx = new ServletContextHandler();
ctx.setContextPath("/");
ctx.addServlet(EmergeEchoServiceSocketServlet.class, websocketServicePoint);

server.setHandler(ctx);
server.addConnector(connector);

// Start the websocket server
server.start();
logger.info("server status: {}", server.dump());
server.join();
```

I created a self-signed certificate and key pair using the recommended command:

```
keytool -keystore keystore -alias jetty -genkey -keyalg RSA
```

I'm at a loss at this point as I believe I have set the embedded WebSocket servlet up properly.  So I figure it's something obvious but I just can't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified the code slightly and was able to get the SSL WebSockets server working.  I'm still using the self-signed cert so it's local only.  I can use the IP address but not "localhost" e.g. "wss://192.168.2.115:8443/servicePoint".

Here is the new code:

```
// Setup the websocket server
Server server = new Server();

if (wssEnabled) {
  // HTTP Configuration
  HttpConfiguration https_config = new HttpConfiguration();
  https_config.setSecureScheme("https");
  https_config.setSecurePort(8443);
  https_config.setSendServerVersion(true);
  https_config.setSendDateHeader(false);
  https_config.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

  SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
  sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath("/pathTo//keystore");
  sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePath("/pathTo/keystore");
  logger.info("keystore path: {}", sslContextFactory.getKeyStorePath());
  sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("myPassword");
  sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("myPassword");
  sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePassword("myPassword");
  sslContextFactory.setExcludeCipherSuites(
      "SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
      "SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
      "SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
      "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5",
      "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA",
      "SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA",
      "SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA");

  // SSL Connector
  connector = new ServerConnector(server,
      new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory,HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()),
      new HttpConnectionFactory(https_config));
  connector.setPort(8443);
} else {
  // Basic HTTP connector
  connector = new ServerConnector(server);
  connector.setPort(websocketPort);
}

ServletContextHandler ctx = new ServletContextHandler();
ctx.setContextPath("/");
ctx.addServlet(EmergeEchoServiceSocketServlet.class, "/dF" + websocketServicePoint);

server.setHandler(ctx);
server.addConnector(connector);

// Start the websocket server
server.start();
logger.info("server status: {}", server.dump());
server.join();
```

}

Comment: I would be interested in hearing what in the code cleanup has caused this to work because it's still not obvious to me.